# Django picture error and {% url admin:index %}

Tags: django

I'm making a simple blog using this tutorial http://lightbird.net/dbe/blog.html
I have a question and a problem I would like to address.:]

The problem is my blog doesn't look like the one on light bird example
and the second problem is this syntax {% url admin:index %} at my bbase.html
I didn't register the namespace as admin but as namespace = 'blog' in my main URL ,I don't understand how does this syntax work {% url admin:index %}

[image]
[image]

My main URLconf are :

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.conf import settings
 admin.autodiscover()
 urlpatterns = patterns('',                  
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     url(r'^cool/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),

 )
```

My Blog URLconf are :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns,include,url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
        url(r'^$','main', name='main'),

)
```

My views.py

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage, EmptyPage
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from blog.models import *

def main(request):
    """Main listing."""
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-created")
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 2)

    try: page = int(request.GET.get("page", '1'))
    except ValueError: page = 1

    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response("list.html", dict(posts=posts, user=request.user))
```

My bbase.html which lives in C:\djcode\mysite\blog\templates

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head> <title>{% block title %}MyBlog{% endblock %}</title> </head>

 <body>
     <div id="sidebar"> {% block sidebar %} {% endblock %} </div>
     <div id="container">
         <div id="menu">
             {% block nav-global %}

                 <!-- MENU -->
                 <h3>MyBlog</h3>
                 {% if user.is_staff %}
                 <a href="{% url admin:index %}">Admin</a>
                 <a href="{% url admin:blog_post_add %}">Add post</a>
                 {% endif %}

             {% endblock %}
         </div>

         <div id="content">
             {% block content %}{% endblock %}
         </div>
     </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

My list.html

```
{% extends "bbase.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="main">

         <!-- Posts  -->
         <ul>
             {% for post in posts.object_list %}
                 <div class="title">{{ post.title }}</div>
                 <ul>
                     <div class="time">{{ post.created }}</div>
                     <div class="body">{{ post.body|linebreaks }}</div>
                 </ul>
             {% endfor %}
         </ul>

         <!-- Next/Prev page links  -->
         {% if posts.object_list and posts.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
    <div class="pagination" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: -20px; ">
        <span class="step-links">
            {% if posts.has_previous %}
                <a href= "?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">newer entries &lt;&lt; </a>
            {% endif %}

            <span class="current">
                &nbsp;Page {{ posts.number }} of {{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}
            </span>

            {% if posts.has_next %}
                <a href="?page={{ posts.next_page_number }}"> &gt;&gt; older entries</a>
            {% endif %}
              </span>
          </div>
          {% endif %}

      </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is your issue the missing formatting? If so, it looks like a CSS issue, and therefore not necessarily anything to do with Django templating. Look at the source of your page, and see if it includes a link to a CSS stylesheet. If that link to the stylesheet is broken, you know that's the problem.

Comment: Yeah , I'm missing the css. thank you @David Robinson for addressing the problem . Could you also help me with the other question.

Comment: What version of python and django did you use?

Comment: @cathy , the tutorial is stated for version 1.1 django but i'm using django 2.4 and phython 2.6. I think , i have to implement the css myself but do you remember yesterday you told me how to register a namespace. I registered the namespace='blog') in my main url but in my bbase.html . It's {% url admin:index %} in the tutorial and it's works.How does this work? like where does it point too when i haven't even registered admin

Comment: can I see your settings code. I don't see wrong in your codes for admin.

Comment: http://justpaste.it/1zos ok . The blog works just i don't understand the syntax {% url admin:index %}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url tag `{% url admin:index %}` links to the `index` view of the `admin` app. The admin namespace is correct because you included your admin urls with the pattern:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Note you have not set a namespace for the `admin` app, so it defaults to `admin`.

If you wanted to link to an `index` view in your `blog` app, the you would use `{% url blog:index %}`.

If you are new to Django, I would personally recommend ignoring the namespace functionality when including url patterns. It can be useful if you want to distinguish between two views with the same name in different apps, or two different instances of the same app, but here, it just seems to be causing you unnecessary confusion. On the other hand, I would always recommend [naming your url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns), which solves many many url pattern problems.

Comment: Oh okay so {% url admin:index %} and {% url blog:index %}. are the same?

Comment: They're not really the same, they both link to a view named `index`, but in different namespaces. If you want to link to the `index` view in the `admin` app, use `{% url admin:index %}`. If you want to link to the `index` view in the `blog` app, use `{% url blog:index %}`.

Comment: +1 yes, namespace is nasty. I personally prefer named url patterns